# How to create PKCS12 in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cryptography, pkcs#12

I know there is SecPKCS12Import API to import(parse) PKCS12.

How to create PKCS12 from SecIdentityRef + SecCertificateRef?

I am looking for a way to use native API (Secure framework) rather than integrating OpenSSL (or other 3rd party library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [SecItemExport](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemExport).

```
CFDataRef exportedData;
OSStatus ret = SecItemExport(arrayWithIdentityAndCert,
                             kSecFormatPKCS12,
                             0, /* Use kSecItemPemArmour to add PEM armor */
                             NULL,
                             &exportedData);

if(ret == errSecSuccess)
{
  /* exportedData now contains your PKCS12 data */
}
```

Comment: Do we have any such API or way to do that in iOS? Considering "SecItemExport" is only available for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is API SecKeychainItemExport, which is used internally by SecItemExport.